# How to display a list full width

Tags: html, css

I have an application that display a list with `<ul>` and `<li>` like [in this example](https://casari-asoc.mangoapps.com/sf/MzE2NzFfMTAyMTkzMw).

How can I change its styling so the labels are not wrapped (like HH Pruebas Funcionales) and all numbers are aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **style="white-space: nowrap;"** on li tags. See example below.

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:25%;margin:0px auto">
  <div style="float:left;width:55%;">
    <ul>
        <li style="style=white-space:nowrap;">HH Preubas Functionales</li>
        <li style="style=white-space:nowrap;">HH Preubas Functionales</li>
        <li style="style=white-space:nowrap;">HH Preubas Functionales</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try add more details to make it understandable for future readers

Comment: Hi Sulthan, Will surely add more details from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If I can see the html from the link you posted I can tell for sure, try nowrap attribute , it works for DIV it might work for LI too

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<style type="text/css">
.td{
text-align:right; 
}
table{
color:#999;
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr><td>HH Analisis:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH Core:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH test:</td>
<td class="td">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>HH Total:</td>
<td class="td">19</td></tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use two ul & give them `display:inline-block`

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>This is little big!</li>
  <li>smaller one</li>
  <li>small</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Please check above snippet!